# jQuery AJAX function to set a PHP $_SESSION variable, single checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

my first outing here with Ajax.  i'm trying to capture the value of a single checkbox, and if checked set a PHP $_SESSION variable to true.

in the HTML i have this.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree"/>
and the js is this....not sure what to put in the AJAX data params??
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#agree').click(function(){ 
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'agree.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { agreement:"checked" } //NOT Sure ABout this??
                });      
        })
    });
```

and the PHP, pseudo code perhaps because it is not working..

```
if($_GET['agreement'] == 'checked') {
$_SESSION['hm-agreement'] = true;
     } else {
$_SESSION['hm-agreement'] = false;
```

}

Comment: get your PHP file to work, test that its setting the session, and this javascript *should* do the trick. You'll need session_start(); called before that PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX call seems to be good. May be you should add some debug to your PHP script and take a look with Firebug or other dev tools.

Don't forget to use `start_session()` on your PHP script at **the begin** of the script.
If you ommit this call, the session object does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check if the boxed is checked, your code now sets the session variable to true no matter what you send to the php file.

also used the shorthand get vs. ajax, less code

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree"/>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#agree').click(function(){ 
        $.get('agree.php','agreement=' + ( this.checked ? 1 : 0 ) });
    })
});
```

PHP

```
session_start();
if($_GET['agreement']) {
    $_SESSION['hm-agreement'] = true;
} else {
    $_SESSION['hm-agreement'] = false;
}
```